# Magento HTACCESS query 301 redirect all but admin

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

Hi hopefully someone can help. 
I have added a 301 redirect to change from an old domain name to a new domain. 
The magento build is still on the old domain also (but with no follow / no index)

I want to keep the installation on the old domain also for order reference etc.

I have added the following to the hta access file, but obviously this also stops me being able to access the admin side of the site.

How can I add an exclude on the following so that I can redirect all - apart from the admin and so this can still be accessed.

```
#Redirect from old domain to new domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.b.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php/admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.b.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can change `admin` if you use another path for your admin area.

Answer (score 2):

This version will allow you to still see the admin styles.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php/admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.b.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
# Match the sub domain (if there is one).
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
# %1 is the sub domain (or empty).
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```